# How can I set up a user's permissions so it can execute a bash script to read other users' files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions

I have a web server on a Debian machine and another Debian machine which runs an application. I want to have the web user call a bash script that returns some info for the php to process.

I have already generated ssh keys and paired my web user (www-data) with a user on the target machine (usr_scripts) and I have the following command which runs the bash script on the target machine:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/known_hosts -i /path/to/rsa/key usr_scripts@targetMachine scriptToReadFiles.sh
```

The scriptToReadFiles.sh is a plain bash script that uses `cat` to output some info from different files (`cat /path/to/mainFolder/Folder1/File1`) and I have a function in my php that takes the output and generates a report.

My problem now is that usr_scripts has insufficient permissions to read the files I need. All the files are inside different folders and they have different owners (as the application uses multiple users for different tasks) like that:

```
mainFolder
 |- Folder 1 (owner: user1)
 |   |- File 1 (owner: user1)
 |   |- File 2 (owner: user1)
 |
 |- Folder 2 (owner: user2)
     |- File 1 (owner: user2)
     |- File 2 (owner: user2)
     |- File 3 (owner: user2)
```

Users user1, user2 etc. are dynamically generated from the application (to whose source code I have no access), they are generated as needed, they don’t belong to a certain group and they mustn't have access to other files outside of their designated home folder.

How should I set up my use_scripts user’s privileges so it can read those files?

Comment: Does your filesystem have ACL enabled? If so, you can add an ACL entry to explicitly grant access to your web server process user.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young ACL is not enabled (although it is compatible according to `/boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64` and I'm not that comfortable in messing with the filesystem. If it was my last resort  I would do it but I'm looking for a less invasive way.

Comment: Do you have *any* control over the owner/group/permissions of the mainFolder files?

Comment: @glennjackman I have root access to the machine. my first idea was to use a cron job to `chmod -R` the mainFolder but it seems an overkill to do it every second and it I won't have access to newer files and folders before the `chmod` command.

Comment: By default, what are the permissions of the files? clearly not world-readable. Are they group-readable? Can you add "usr_scripts" to those groups?

Comment: @BasilisP. If you have root access to the machine, you can write simple C program and add sticky bit to it.

Comment: @glennjackman I cannot edit my questions yet but the Folder permissions are `drwxrwx---` and the file permissions are either `-rw-r--r--` or `-rw-rw----`. By adding World Execute to the folders and world Read to the files (that doesn’t have it already) everything works so I guess one approach is to alter the default permissions for folders and files created within mainFolder but I’m still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use chmod to change the modes of the current files and umask to change the future files.
here is a link to some info for umask
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html